# Interaction Studio Web pop without sitemap

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations, interaction-studio, personalization

is it possible to create a web campaign (exit intent) without the sitemap configuration. I know that, to have a web campaign on the website, we need to define a content zone and this can be done via sitemap. Let me know if there are any other ways possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to define a content zone is through the sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the Client Side scripts you can target areas that are not content zones. Depending on your execution you would lose tracking and the Flicker Defender leverage.